Impact of Time Shift $(\tau)$ on Autocorrelation for a Rectangular Pulse Train Process
I've been studying the autocorrelation function of a rectangular pulse train process, and I came across an interesting situation on this site link here where a time shift $\tau$ was introduced. In the example, $()$ is given by:
$$\mathcal Y(t) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathcal B_k p\left({t-kT}\right), \ -\infty < t < \infty\tag{1} $$
where $p(t)$ represents the rectangular pulse function, and $\mathcal B_k$ are the random variables associated with the pulse amplitudes. I also found that for another process $X(t)$ defined as:
$$\mathcal X(t) = \mathcal Y(t- \mathcal T) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathcal B_k p\left({t - \mathcal T -kT}\right), \ -\infty < t < \infty.\tag{2}$$
the autocorrelation function is computed as:
$\begin{align}E[\mathcal X(t)\mathcal X(t+\tau)] &= A^2\cdot \left(1 - \frac{|\tau|}{T}\right). \tag{3}
\end{align}$
I’m struggling to understand how the introduction of the time shift $\tau$ affects the autocorrelation function in the context of the rectangular pulse train. Specifically, I would like to know:

Why $Y(t)$ is not $WSS$ and $X(t)$ is?

How does the function $R_{Y}(\tau)$ change compared to the function obtained for $R_{X}(\tau)$, and what are the implications of this difference?



$ \mathcal T$ is not a simple time shift but a random variable itself. That means the location of each rectangular pulse gets shuffled around randomly and they are not at regular intervals any more.

This question is similar to: Hard time figuring out whether the following random process is wide sense stationary. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DilipSarwate I read the answer to par Avant Yes I put the link of your answer I put this question hoping that someone explains me the answer that you gave

@DilipSarwate it's about the same question I was trying to understand your answer in that question

@Hilmar "the location of each rectangular pulse gets shuffled around randomly and they are not at regular intervals any more" Not so. Each pulse gets delayed by the same  amount $\tau$ where $\tau$ is the value that $\mathcal T$ has taken on. Thus, each sample path is a uniformly spaced rectangular pulse train, the pulses are still at regular intervals of $T$ with no overlap(as described  in $(1)$) but delayed by $\tau$.

The autocorrelation function of any random process is a function of two variables. Thus, if $\{X(t)\}$ is a random process, then
$$R_X(t_1, t_2)= E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$$ and it has the property that for each time instant $t$,
$$R_X(t,t) = E[X(t)X(t)] = E[(X(t))^2] \geq 0.$$
Now, consider the process $\{\mathcal Y(t)\}$ in the OP's question where
$$\mathcal Y(t) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathcal B_k p\left({t-kT}\right), \ -\infty < t < \infty.\tag{1}$$
While that gobblydook description in $(1)$ suggests that $\mathcal Y(t)$ is an enormously complicated function of the $\mathcal B_k$'s, it is in fact much simpler than it looks. The definition of $p(t)$ is
$$p(t) = \begin{cases}1, & 0 \leq t < T,\\0, & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$
and so
$$p(t-kT) = \begin{cases}1, & kT \leq t < (k+1)T,\\0, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Note that we have partitioned the entire time axis into disjoint time intervals $[kT,(k+1)T), k \in \mathbb Z$, and thus, whatever the value of the real number $t$ might happen to be, $t$ is in one and only one of these time intervals (say $[kT,(k+1)T)$ for concreteness), only  $p(t-kT)$ has value $1$ and all other $p(t-k^\prime T)$'s have value $0$, and that mountainous sum in $(1)$ simplifies to the molehill of
$$\text{If }kT \leq t < (k+1)T, \text{then } \mathcal Y(t) = \mathcal B_k.$$
With that as preliminaries, let us return to $R_{\mathcal Y}(t_1, t_2)$ and note that it has value $E[\mathcal B_k \mathcal B_k] = A^2$ if $t_1$ and $t_2$ both belong to the same interval $[kT,(k+1)T)$, and value $E[\mathcal B_k \mathcal B_{k^\prime}] = 0$ if $t_1$ and $t_2$ belong to two different intervals $[kT,(k+1)T)$ and $[k^\prime T,(k^\prime +1)T)$. We cannot say with a straight face that $R_{\mathcal Y}(t_1, t_2)$ can be expressed as a function only of the difference $t_2-t_1$ between the two time instants $t_1$ and $t_2$, because for any fixed difference (say $t_2-t_1 = 0.2T$), the value of $R_{\mathcal Y}(t_1, t_2)$ is $A^2$ if $t_1$ and $t_2$ lie in the same interval (e.g. $t_1 = 3.3T, t_2 = 3.5T$), and value $0$ if $t_1$ and $t_2$ lie in different intervals (e.g. $t_1 = 3.9T, t_2 = 4.1T$). We are thus reluctantly forced to conclude that $\{\mathcal Y(t)\}$ is not a WSS process.

can we change the sequence to 0 and A , where $E[\mathcal B_k\mathcal B_{k^\prime}]=\frac{A^2}{4}$

when we change the sequence : if $t_1$ and $t_2$ belong to two adjacent pulses here we have $E[\mathcal B_k\mathcal B_{k^\prime}]=\frac{A^2}{4}$ than how to get the $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty E\left[ p\left({t - \mathcal T -kT}\right)p\left({s - \mathcal T -kT}\right)\right]$

@MouhKramo $\mathcal B_k$ is a random variable that takes on value $\pm A$ with equal probability, and so $E[\mathcal B_k^2] =A^2$ while $E[\mathcal B_k \mathcal B_{k^\prime}] =\frac 14 [A^2 + (-A^2] + A(-A)+(-A)A] = 0.$

can we change that sequence -A to a 0

how we dill with this $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k^\prime=-\infty}^\infty E[\mathcal B_k \mathcal B_{k^\prime}]E\left[ p\left({t - \mathcal T -kT}\right)p\left({s - \mathcal T -k^\prime T}\right)\right]$ when $\mathcal B_k \mathcal B_{k^\prime}$ having different probabilities like($\frac 14$ and $\frac 34$) or the sequences are 0 or A

@MouhKramo Those are wholly different questions, and I refuse to modify my answer to respond to them.  Ask a separate question if you like.
